# Printing datastructure from input doesn't work

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, queue

I'm trying to create a program which prints a datastructure from the input. The input and output looks like this: http://puu.sh/kDMc9/2d46462d4d.png. So for example, in the first test case: the first line indicates how many lines will follow in that case. Then if it's the number 1 as the first number on a line it means that you want to add elements to stack/queue/priority-queue and 2 means you want to take out an element, so the second number on a line is the value. Then the output prints if it's stack,queue, priority-queue, impossible or not sure(can be more than one)

This is the code I have now:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class DataStructure {

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    while(calculate());
}

private static boolean calculate()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberOfRowsPerCase = input.nextInt();

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    Queue<Integer> queue = new Queue<Integer>();
    PriorityQueue<Integer> prioQueue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
    boolean stackBool = true;
    boolean queueBool = true;
    boolean prioQueueBool = true;

    int next;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfRowsPerCase; i++)
    {
                next = input.nextInt();
                if(next == 1)
                {
                    next = input.nextInt();

                    stack.push(next);
                    queue.enqueue(next);
                    prioQueue.add(next);

                }

                else if(next == 2)
                {
                    next = input.nextInt();
                    if(!stack.pop().equals(next))
                    {
                        stackBool = false;
                    }

                    else if(!queue.dequeue().equals(next))
                    {
                        queueBool = false;
                    }

                    else if(!prioQueue.poll().equals(next))
                    {
                        prioQueueBool = false;
                    }


                }


                if(stackBool == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("stack");
                }

                else if(queueBool == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("queue");
                }

                else if(prioQueueBool == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("priority queue");
                }

                else if((stackBool == true && queueBool == true) || (queueBool == true && prioQueueBool == true) || (stackBool == true && prioQueueBool == true))
                {
                    System.out.println("not sure");
                }

                else
                {
                    System.out.println("impossible");
                }

    }


    //Check EOF 
    String in;
    in = input.nextLine();
    in = input.nextLine();
    if(in.equals(""))
    {
        return false;
    }


    return true;

}

}
```

But when I run the test-case on the picture above, my program prints this: https://ideone.com/mIO1bs which is wrong. I can't find why it does that, can anyone else here maybe see?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your logic setting the boolean flags is correct then this part

```
if(stackBool == true)
{
    System.out.println("stack");
}
...
else if((stackBool == true && queueBool == true) || (queueBool == true && prioQueueBool == true) || (stackBool == true && prioQueueBool == true))
{
    System.out.println("not sure");
}
```

will never work as intended because parts of the second condition were already caught by the first condition.

The better suggestion is to come up with a clearer way of representing this. A suggestion that will still probably work is to put your more complicated if statements at the start of the if-else chain.

---

Disregarding above assumption:

```
if(!stack.pop().equals(next))
{
    stackBool = false;
}

else if(!queue.dequeue().equals(next))
{
    queueBool = false;
}

else if(!prioQueue.poll().equals(next))
{
    prioQueueBool = false;
}
```

These should not be `else`s, they're all completely independent.

Comment: Alright this approach with booleans is the only one I have come up with. There isn't a way to change the else if there so it works?

Comment: I'll just quote the answerer "put your more complicated if statements at the start of the if-else chain."

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that, read too fast. I did that change and it printed this: https://ideone.com/tOSv2p so nothing changed. It seems to always run the first if-statement so maybe it's wrong where I set them to false.

Comment: Okay there's another problem... I'll edit my answer. edit: Updated.

Comment: @user2597001 It is updated. Here's a comment notifying you.

Comment: Alright that's true. I changed those else so they are all if there. But then I got this: https://ideone.com/2pjGS8 which isn't right so i'm not sure if those if are wrong or the problem is somewhere else.